# How can I send a raw ethernet frame only by mac address?

Tags: ethernet, autosar

I have a PA SPC58XG board communicating via ethernet. Using Autosar stack I want to check weather Ethernet configurations are correct. for this I want to send a dummy low level frame just to see if the frame is received by the PA board in the configured DMA buffer.

**can I send a raw frame using only the PA mac address ?**

Answer (score 0):

To check whether your board can receive Ethernet frames just send any type of broadcast from a connected node (e.g. an ARP request for a local IP) - it should show up in the buffer.

Checking transmissions are a bit harder. You have to assemble an Ethernet frame (possibly a simple LLDP frame), make sure the FCS is correctly calculated and send it. On another network node run a packet capture and see if you can pick up the frame you sent.

The broadcast MAC as destination is probably a good choice to start with as well. The source MAC doesn't really matter for the first tests.